# odata4j - getting an exception when executing a functioncall

Tags: android, odata, odata4j

I want to execute the functioncall GetProductsByRating from the [services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/](http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/) odata web-service endpoint, using odata4j.

My code is the following:

```
Enumerable<OObject> e = consumer.callFunction("GetProductsByRating").pInt32("rating", 3).execute();
```

When i run this code, I get the following exception:

`05-23 11:52:13.343: W/System.err(2794): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.`

Can anybody tell if the current version (0.7) already handles these function call responses and if not, when it will?

I also would like to know if there is some alternative to obtain a response from this type of operation. An alternative Android/Java library or method would be ideal.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, unfortunately I can't provide you valuable answers for all of your questions. I only know that version (0.7) should not handle function/actions calls yet. So the answer is no. When it will? I would say it could be probably part of odata4j-0.9.0. For reference you can see this open issue: http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/issues/detail?id=224 (I was forced to build it using maven without tests run)

Comment: Thank you tsykora. I'm now using Xpath for retrieving the useful data from the function response. Unfortunately, I cannot wait for the odata4j-0.9.0 version. So thanks again for the information.